# Why Photoshop changes edges/borders colours when scaling/distorting up/down?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, vector, shapes, bitmap

I'm annoyed with this behaviour since forever, so its time to ask: why Photoshop change edges colours when there's clearly absolutely no reason to do so? Here is an example: I'm dealing with the logo from my firm, plain squares, straight pixels.

[image]

Its a colorbar in a sofa shape. 
As you can see below, the edges are really hard, no smoothing whatsoever.

[image]

Now, I want to turn this into a square like this:

[image]

Looks almost fine. 
But when I zoom in:

[image]

I know it is supposed to help optical viewing and stuff, works great for photos, thats the name of the software, ok. But guess what? I don't want that now.

**Is there any way of turning this behaviour off?**

PS: I have a vector version of the logo and I know how to do that in Illustrator, but I'm asking for a philosophical reason (and for the glory of Satan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a default interpolation method to use whenever Photoshop resamples image data. Choose Edit > Preferences > General (Windows) or Photoshop > Preferences > General (Mac OS), and then choose a method from the Image Interpolation Methods menu.

In your case need change to: **Nearest Neighbor** (Default: Bicubic)

Also possible specify interpolation in resize window in Resample option:

- Mac OS:

[image: Photoshop Resize GUI MacOS]

- Windows:

[image]

If you are using transform techniques like scale or distort, remember to change the interpolation method in the tool options bar:

[image]

Comment: Seemed very promissor, but nothing changed. Same crappy borders. And oddly enough, the preview before applying the changes looks perfect.

Comment: Just realised I must also change the tool preferences. Thank you.